# Is there a way to create a conditional comparator in java?

Tags: java, comparator

Suppose I have a class that contains three fields:

```
class Component {
    private String color;
    private int weight;
    private TreeSet<Component> components = new TreeSet<Component>(new CustomComparator());
}
```

Is there a way to create CustomComparator so that it sorts the components into the TreeSet based on their color if and only if all the components have the same weight (otherwise, it sorts them according to their weight), without having to create additional comparators or methods?

Comment: If you really want to sort 'based on their color if and only if all the components have the same weight' you would probably get the best solution by using two comparators, one for weight and another for color, then check for the condition and use then the appropriate comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

```
new Comparator<Component>() {
  @Override public int compare(Component left, Component right) {
    int cmp = Integer.compare(left.weight, right.weight);
    if (cmp == 0) {
      cmp = left.color.compareTo(right.color);
    }
    return cmp;
  }
};
```

Or, if you can use third-party libraries, Guava's `ComparisonChain` makes this even nicer:

```
new Comparator<Component>() {
  @Override public int compare(Component left, Component right) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
       .compare(left.weight, right.weight)
       .compare(left.color, right.color)
       .result();
  }
};
```

Or, if you're on Java 8:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(Component::getWeight) // must have a getter
   .thenComparing(Component::getColor);
```

Comment: I do not think this conforms to the requirement 'based on their color if and only if all the components have the same weight'.

Comment: I believe this to be what the OP meant.

Comment: That's possible as your answer is accepted. In that case the OP formulated his question quite poorly. Apart from that nice answer. I usually go for apache CompareToBuilder and include null check.

Comment: My implementations throw NullPointerException on null inputs, which I consider correct behavior. I'm not certain what CompareToBuilder would get you over the implementations I've described.

Comment: CompareToBuilder does not give you anything over your solutions, it's just another way of doing the comparison. I think the handling of nulls is philosophy question, it's ok for me if you prefer the NPE.